# Accepted Common Pattern for Throttling Login (or other) Requests in a PHP MVC Application

Tags: php, security, model-view-controller, codeigniter

Is there a commonly accepted pattern (or class library, or etc.) for throttling certain form submissions for PHP MVC applications?  I'm specifically thinking of the scenario where someone is running a dictionary attack against one of your login forms, and you want to block them after X requests in Y seconds, or if a certain pattern of requests is detected.

Specific questions:

Do any frameworks come with this functionality built in?  If not, what's a common way of implementing this in a web based, PHP MVC architecture?

Is this something that should be handled at the application layer, or should the web server itself be dealing with this kind of malfeasance?

I can think of a number of ways to implement this, but it seems like the kind of things all applications should have, and therefore a general solution should already exist.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about formal patterns, but break-in prevention has several standard techniques:

- In response to an unsuccessful login attempt, delay several seconds before any response.  This puts a lid on the rate of break ins.
- Don't punish a local account—punish any host making a series of break in attempts.  Stop offering a login prompt after 3 or 4 sequential failures no matter which account is targeted.
- Maybe invoke [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha) under some circumstances, like in a financial system.

I don't know of any built-in application solutions, but certainly the building blocks are all there, easily assembled, and highly debatable if it is appropriate to invoke them.